# Using Docker's CMD to run a Shell Script + Get Output

Tags: docker

I've been using a docker file for about 6 months now without issue but after a few changes in compute engine, I'm hitting a weird issue where something in my start up script is behaving the way it should / it used to.

I have a shell script that does a couple tweaks to the environment before starting a web server which is started like so:

```
ADD src/docker/startup.sh /home/gauntface/docker/startup.sh

CMD /home/gauntface/docker/startup.sh
```

`startup.sh` echo's logs but I can't find a way to view these logs, does anyone have any advice?

`docker logs` shows nothing for my container

#### Additional Notes

I'm running the docker command with daemon mode. Without Daemon mode, docker throws this error:

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

The Docker file and start up script are here:

https://github.com/gauntface/gf-site/blob/staging/src/docker/Dockerfile-base

https://github.com/gauntface/gf-site/blob/staging/src/docker/startup.sh

Comment: From the error message it sounds like you need to run `docker` with the `-t` option to allocate a pseudo tty to the process. Possibly `-i` to keep stdin open as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker logs` by default will show the output from stdout/stderr:

```
$ docker run -it --name test-it busybox echo hello world
hello world

$ docker logs test-it
hello world
```

We'd need to know more about your shell script, what output it generates, and what debugging you've done to give a more detailed answer about why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added links to the startup script. I noticed you weren't using daemon mode which I was, but running without daemon on computer engine throws an error (again added to original question)

Comment: if you `docker exec -it container_id bash` and then launch your startup.sh, do you have your logs?

Comment: As Matt indicates in the comment above, you need to include a `-t` if you need a tty. You can run with `-itd` which will detach but make available stdin and a tty for when you later attach. Logs will work just fine with `-d`.